# Создание и настройка git-репозитория на своём сервере

Tags: git, сервер, linux-mint, git-репозиторий

> fatal: '/python/chr/' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

---

Сервер

---

```
git init --bare
nano post-receive


#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/admin/web/ploshadka.net/public_html/test --git-dir=/home/admin/web/ploshadka.net/git checkout -f
chmod +x post-receive
```

---

Локалка

---

```
git init 
git add .
git remote add live ssh://root@123.123.111.1/python/chr/
git push live main
```

> fatal: '/python/chruches/' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                     and the repository exists.

Пытался по новой создавать, одно и тоже, создавал новых юзеров, тоже особо не помогло, одно и тоже

Comment: Забыл добавить, что ветку main создал)

Answer (score 1):

Ох))
Вместо

```
git remote add live ssh://root@123.123.111.1/python/chr/
```

Использовал

```
git remote add live ssh://root@123.123.111.1/~/python/chr/
```